# `NullPointerException` on swing AWT thread - cursor update on JLightweightFrame

Tags: java, swing, javafx, nullpointerexception

I have a `NullPointerException` in my application, that happens only on one specific PC, and is reproducible. I wrote my GUI using Javafx with some Swing JPanels on it via SwingNode.

**What should I do?**

```
Exception-Time = 2016-08-30 06:55:50  UTC Exception-Tag = 0 Exception-Message = Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 (Id = 55) throw exception: null Stack-Trace = java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.swing.JLightweightFrame.updateClientCursor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.JLightweightFrame.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.JLightweightFrame$1.updateCursor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WLightweightFramePeer.updateCursorImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.updateCursorImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: First check to make sure that  you're starting your GUI on the Swing event thread correctly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The OP says: *"I wrote my GUI using Javafx with some Swing JPanels on it via SwingNode."*; so the GUI should be *started* on the FX Application Thread, with the creation of the `SwingNode` content being delegated to the AWT event dispatch thread. It at least appears this is happening, from the stack trace; but without actual code it's hard to know for sure. (Guess I am in a pedantic mood today...)

Comment: @James_D: thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 3):

**More about the problem:**

Apparently, this is a bug at the JDK itself (versions 8 and 9) and probably won't get fixed until JDK10.

This exception is thrown from within the `sun.swing.JLightweightFrame.java` class, at the `updateClientCursor` function (lines 472-749):

```
private void updateClientCursor() {
    Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, this);
    Component target = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(this, p.x, p.y);
    if (target != null) {
        content.setCursor(target.getCursor());
    }
}
```

In general, this is happening because `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` can return NULL, for example, when you move between graphic devices. 'MouseInfo' can still hold the former graphic device information, then `getPointerInfo()` can return NULL if the mouse already moved to the new graphic device and `MouseInfo` still didn't updated to the new graphic device information. this scenario will cause a `Null Pointer Exception` on this line `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` for trying to run a method of a NULL object.

For me, NPE is thrown when I move my JavaFX app window between monitors on my multiscreen machine. Its not happening every time but it is reproducible very easily.
I'm using a Swing component in a JavaFX SwingNode component.

This bug is already [a known issue](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8185890) at Oracle bug list.

**Code Fix:**
This snippet shows an optional fix for this bug:

```
private void updateClientCursor() {
    PointerInfo pointerInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    if (pointerInfo == null) {
        /*
         * This can happen when JavaFX cannot decide
         * which graphics device contains the current
         * mouse position.
         */
        return;
    }
    Point p = pointerInfo.getLocation();
    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, this);
    Component target = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(this, p.x, p.y);
    if (target != null) {
        content.setCursor(target.getCursor());
    }
}
```

[Taken from JetBrains repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/commit/894a403ac139608fe8db25f3ec26b01a1a9a5692)

**Optional solution:**

Since it is a bug withing the formal Oracle JDK, there is no much I can do about it. there are fixes applied in other non-formal JDKs like [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) for example, which applied a fix, but I don't know which version will apply this fix yet.

For me, I would probably try to compile and use my own JDK with the applied fix and use it in my project, but this is a hard to maintain and not so flexible solution. If someone have another fix/workaround I would be happy to hear.

Comment: I wonder whether ComponentFactory.getMouseInfoPeer() can also return null.  Component.findUnderMouseInWindow uses that method without checking for null.